# Parallax scrolling and alternating text simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

To preface, this might be helpful to see: http://www.sbs.com.au/theboat/

I am trying to replicate a similar effect here: https://codepen.io/summeropratt/pen/ExgXYwa

```html
<div class="first-section"></div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <section class="cards">
        <div class="center cards--inner">
          <div class="card" data-rellax-speed="-3">
            <h2>info 1</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="card" data-rellax-speed="0">
            <h2>info 2</h2>
          </div> 
          <div class="card" data-rellax-speed="1">
            <h2>info 3</h2>
          </div> 
          <div class="card" data-rellax-speed="3">
            <h2>info 4</h2>
          </div>  
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
<div class="last-section"></div>
```

Here is what I am struggling with:

1. I would ideally like the text to fade in and out. First you see "info 1" fade into view then fade out before seeing "info 2" fade in/out, etc.
2. In the current snippet, the parallax scrolling starts as soon as your mouse hovers the element. This is an issue when your mouse is towards the bottom of your screen and the entire ".card-body" is not in view. It cuts off the content. I understand why, but how can I get around this? I want the entire view to be the blue background and nothing else.

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: Yes, @GetSet! Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/summeropratt/pen/ExgXYwa